# Ant: How to force java compilation if classpath jars have changed but sources have not

Tags: java, ant, jar, classpath, javac

I have the following usecase:
I have a java project (myProj) which uses a common.jar from a different project(common).   I want the javac ant task to work even if the sources of myProj have not changed **if** the common.jar has changed (as the sources of myProj depend of it and might be invalid now).
I have a task which copies the common.jar from a central location to the myProj lib if it has changed and I can use it to set a property whether or not to "force" compilation so that end is taken care of.
I'm not sure how (or if) I can tell the javac task to try and compile anyway? I don't want to change myProj's sources (or timestamps) so that the task will start.
Excerpt from the ant build.xml file:

```
<path id="project.class.path">  
<pathelement location... />  
...  
<fileset dir="lib" includes="**/*.jar" />  
</path>  
<target name="copyLibs" >  
<copy file="${central.loc}/common.jar" todir="lib" />  
...  
</target>  
<target name="javac" >  
<javac srcdir="src" includes="**" excludes=... >  
<classpath refid="project.class.path"/>  
</javac>  
</target>
```

Thanks in advance,
Ittai

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `delete` task before `javac` to clean old compiled classes:

In general java classes should not be recompiled if the API of the dependent classes haven't changed.

Also I would suggest using maven as it handles dependencies more gracefully.

Comment: @Vitaly Thanks, I was hoping for a more "in-house" solution but I guess this will do. I suddenly realized that I don't know how to check if copy actually moved a newer common.jar file or not. Would you mind if I update the question to include this also or would you rather I open a new question on how to perform that check?

Comment: I would suggest opening another one, but It's your call

Comment: @Vitaly Thanks, I've accepted your answer and posted another question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4533925/ant-how-to-know-if-at-least-one-copy-task-from-ten-copy-tasks-actually-copied-a I'd appreciate it if you think you can help me there as well

Comment: If you follow ANT best practices, you will have a `clean` target in your build that deletes the generated build artifacts. Simply execute `ant clean javac`, or you can create a target that depends on both `clean` and `javac` (e.g. `clean-javac`).

Comment: @Mads Thanks but that would mean that every time that build is run it will compile all the classes. This is something I wish to avoid. I want to compile the classes only if the sources have changed OR if one of the libs has changed

Comment: @Ittai - in that case, then you might consider using the `uptodate` task http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/uptodate.html to know when to `delete` the *.class files before invoking `javac`.